# C# - Extract Date from String using StreamReader

Tags: c#, csv, parsing, datetime

How would I go about getting just the date from the following string?

"DateOfTest_01-30-2018-1_003"

This string is in position 8 in a CSV file, which I am looping through and parsing.  What I have is:

```
while (!reader.EndOfStream) {
    var splitLine = reader.ReadLine().SplitCommaSeparatedValues();
    sample.RunDate = splitLine[8];
    WriteLog("Run Date = " + sample.RunDate);}
```

So I need to extract characters from the string that fall between "_" and "-1" and convert the result to /mm/dd/yyyy format.

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: So have you tried it yourself yet? I don't see any code to try and parse the date out. You already understand how to split strings, why not split on `_` and then `-` and pick the appropriate parts of the array?

Comment: If the date is always in the same position you can use [string.Substring()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) `sample.RunDate.Substring(11, 10)`.

Answer (score 0):

Better will be regular expression in this case: "(DateOfTest_)(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})(-\d_\d{3})". Second group will be date. In c# you can use Regex.Match. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/twcw2f1c(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateTime.ParseExact`:

```
var culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
var strToParse = splitLine[8].Substring(11, 10);
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(strToParse, "MM-dd-yyyy", culture);
var formattedStr = date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", culture);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Regex` matching to determine date string in the input.

```
var pattern = @"(?<=_)(.*?)(?=-1)";
var input = "DateOfTest_01-30-2018-1_003";
if (Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern))
{
    var dateStr = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
    var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateStr.Value, "MM-dd-yyyy",null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you absolutely need the data at just that exact moment move your date parser outside of your reader.

After that, the answer really relies on whether or not the string in that field is always formatted the same way.

As others have pointed out, if the string is always of the same format you can substring the date out of the string.  Then you can either do use one of the several built-in date format methods, or since it is formatted correctly, do a string.Replace("-", "//")

If the string format changes you'll need to try some regex to help you identify the substring to pull out.

My biggest point is that I think you should do this formatting of your field outside of your reader.

Answer (score 0):

```
string TestString = "DateOfTest_01-30-2018-1_003";
Regex TestRegex = new Regex(@"(DateOfTest_)(\d{2}-\d{2}-20\d{2})(-\d_\d{3})");
string ExactDateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy";

        if (TestRegex.IsMatch(TestString))
        {
            Date = TestRegex.Match(TestString).Groups[2].ToString();
            Date = DateTime.ParseExact(Date, ExactDateFormat, null).ToShortDateString();
        }
```